# How to perform load testing on website with https protocol

Tags: jmeter

I need to perform a load Testing for scenario where certain number of user are hitting website at once , 
Think work fine but , I am getting error when it hit for 300 user thread with Handshake protocol , after that remaining thread works fine .

Is there some thing I am missing .

Comment: can u provide code/error?

Comment: what do you want to achieve? see http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html